# Laravel 8 Auth::attempt () always return false except only the first user I created

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 8 and I have a registration form and it creates user successful and auth::attempts works at the same time of creating user  as following code

```
 public function createUser(Request $request){

    $user=User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->get();
    //return response($user);
    if($user->isEmpty()){


    $user=new User();

    $user->name=$request->input('full_name');
    $user->email=$request->input('user_email');
    $password=Hash::make($request->input('user_password'));
    $user->password=$password;
    
        $result=$user->save();
        if($result){
            $user->attachRole('user');
            Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('user_email'), 'password' => 
            $request->input('user_password')],true);
            return redirect()->route('user_profile');
          }
    }
```

but when the user try to login, the attempt function always return false although the email and password are correct
here is the login code

```
public function doLogin(Request $request){
    
    
    $login=Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->input('user_email'), 'password'=>$request->input('user_password')],true);
    
    
    if($login)
    return redirect()->route('user_profile');
    return redirect()->route('user_login');

}
```

but if I tried to login with the first user it login successfuly

Answer (score 0):

Check with your database if new user being saved and if yes check dump of ($request->all()) in doLogin() method.

Comment: new user is created . how i can check dump ?

Comment: public function doLogin(Request $request){
    
    dd($request->all());
    $login=Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->input('user_email'), 'password'=>$request->input('user_password')],true);
    
    
    if($login)
    return redirect()->route('user_profile');
    return redirect()->route('user_login');

}